# C# - Interface setting property to { get, set } another interface

Tags: c#, interface

So, I was writing two interfaces on the following structure:

```
public interface IBar 
{
    string DoStuff();
}

public interface IFoo 
{
    IBar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

On my implementation of `IFoo`, I have to do things like:

```
public class FooImpl : IFoo 
{
    private BarImpl _barImpl;

    public IBar Bar
    {
        get { return _barImpl }
        set { _barImpl = (BarImpl) value }
    }
}
```

And then I will always have to be casting things around while using it, unless I manage some implicit operator which I don't want to.

So, is there a better way to write this in order to not cast things around and maybe have a clean `Property { get; set; }` on my implementations?

**EDIT**
Just to clarify why I (think) I need it this way: Let's say on my `FooImpl` I will need specific methods of `BarImpl` to work with. But `DoStuff()`, which are common to all `IBars` may be called from another places like `fooImpl.Bar.DoStuff()`. Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Does FooImpl *require* BarImpl?

Comment: This is bad design, you should not cast to `BarImpl` but instead treat it like `IBar` all the way. If you can't/won't do that, you should have the `Bar` property be of type `BarImpl` to begin with.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: @JoãoMenighin I think you misunderstand the real purpose of an interface. The idea is that the consumers should not need to know the implementation. Have you thought of adding the needed member into the `IBar` interface itself? Or maybe what you really need is `public interface IFoo  { BarImpl Bar { get; set; } }` and not an `IBar` interface

Comment: @Vikhram thanks for the answer... I'm still on the designing fase so I really do not know if I should put the method on the `IBar` itself or if I should only use the Implementation... I was just wondering if there was a better way, but, from the answers, I get it is just bad design (and, therefore, there is not good way of doing it)

Answer (score 2):

How about to use a generic interface? Try this code:

```
public interface IFoo<T> where T : IBar
{
    T Bar { get; set; }
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo<BarImpl>
{
    private BarImpl _barImpl;

    public BarImpl Bar
    {
        get { return _barImpl; }
        set { _barImpl = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constructor there which takes object of `IBar` type parameter and pass the `BarImpl` from outside the class which will add loose coupling to it like:

```
public class FooImpl : IFoo 
{
    private IBar _barImpl;

    public IBar Bar
    {
        get { return _barImpl }
        set { _barImpl =  value; }
    }

    public FooImpl(IBar bar)
    {
        _barImpl  = bar;
    } 
}
```

and in this case you would want to make your `IBar` property read only so that it's can't be changed from outside, so just add getter in it like:

```
public IBar Bar
{
    get { return _barImpl; }       
}
```

This way your `FooImpl` only knows about the interface and is not tightly bound with the implementation of the `IBar` and any implementation could be passed from outside.

Now when creating instance of `FooImpl` you will have to pass the `BarImpl` as parameter :

```
BarImpl bar = new BarImpl();
var foo = new FooImpl(bar);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I liked this answer... Havent thought about it, but please see my edit. I think it wont apply

Comment: the solution suggested above would work fine what you are asking in edit

Comment: Yeah I mean, it would but then I would have to cast the other way around: When I want to use specific methods of the `BarImpl` on my `FooImpl`, I would have t o cast it... Thinking of it, I don't think there is a way to escape casting... Maybe with the Generics suggested, Will have a look on it.

Comment: no you wouldn't need to cast, it would call the implementation of the instance of `BarImpl` which was passed as input via constructor

Comment: I don't think you get it. If `BarImpl` has a method called `DoAnotherStuff()` I would have to make `((BarImpl) _barImpl).DoAnotherStuff()` in order to call it on my `FooImpl`.

Comment: yes, of-course you would have to, but why would you need to call those inside the `IFoo` ?

Comment: That's what I am wondering haha... Im still on the designing fase so maybe it is just bad design if I have to make that... I will come back to this as soon as I have a best picture of what I REALLY need... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching the concept of Interfaces the wrong way. In absolute, `IFoo` shouldn't require a specific implementation of `IBar`. In your `IFoo` implementation, remove the any reference to `BarImpl` and replace it with `IBar`.

If, for an extraordinary reason, `FooImpl` can only work with `BarImpl`, and no other implementations, then in your IoC registrations just set it that way. Can't guide you through that if I don't know which IoC container you're using. If you're not using IoC at all, you can just instantiate the proper type of `IBar` of course.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin I read you edit, but it's hard to help you without knowing your actual case. If `IFoo` needs something specific from `BarImpl`, maybe it should be in the `IBar` interface, or maybe `IBar` is too generic and you'd need another interface for the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    private BarImpl _barImpl;

    public BarImpl Bar
    {
        get { return _barImpl; }
        set { _barImpl = value; }
    }

    IBar IFoo.Bar
    {
        get { return _barImpl; }
        set { _barImpl = (BarImpl)value; }
    }
}
```

In this case, any time you are working with an object of type `FooImpl`, the `Bar` property will return a `BarImpl` type, removing the need to cast it in calling code.  However, the class still implements `IFoo` properly and will return an `IBar` reference in any context where it is used as an `IFoo` reference.

This implementation becomes even cleaner if you can change `IFoo.Bar` to be read-only and instead require `IFoo` implementers to get their `IBar` member through a constructor or other means.  This allows a `FooImpl` to require a `BarImpl` implementation of `IBar` without casting in the `IFoo.Bar` setter.